# Why would valuation for a swap be the same on the backward and forward rate but not a caplet

Tags: options, interest-rates, monte-carlo, risk-neutral-measure, arbitrage

Consider for time discretization $0 = T_{0} < T_{1} <... < S < T < T_{n}$, and the corresponding forward rates and backward rate:

$\text{Forward rate: }L(S,T;t)$

$\text{Backward Rate: }I(S,T):=\frac{1}{T-S}(\frac{R(T)}{R(S)}-1)$

where $$R(\{T_{0} ,...,T_{n}\};t):=P(T_{m(t)+1};t)\prod\limits_{i=0}^{m(t)}(1+L_{i}(T_{i},T_{i+1};T_{i})(T_{i+1}-T_{i})),\; \; \;\\ m(t):=\max\{{i\in \{0,...,n}\}:T_{i}\leq t\}$$

Now why would the Monte Carlo valuation of the both the

$\textbf{Caplet on Forward Rate}$ and the  $\textbf{Caplet on Backward Rate}$ not be equal

BUT the Monte Carlo valuation of both the

$\textbf{Swap on Forward Rate}$ and the  $\textbf{Swap on Backward Rate}$

are (nearly) equal.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Before I look for an answer: you are using $R(T;t)$ and $R(S;t)$ but define only $R(t)\,.$ What is the exact definition?

Comment: My apologies $R(t)$ is the accrual account at time $t$ given the discretization $T_{0},...,T_{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the distance between the $T_i$ is small then
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\frac{R(T)}{R(S)}=\prod_{i=m(S)}^{m(T)}1+L(T_i,T_{i+1};T_i)\Delta_i\approx\exp\left(\int_S^Tr(u)\,du\right)\,.
\end{align}
On the other hand,
$$\tag{2}
1+L(S,T,S)\Delta=\frac{1}{P(S,T)}
$$
where $P(S,T)$ is the conditional zero bond price
$$
P(S,T)=\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_S^Tr(u)\,du\Big) \Big|{\cal F}_S\Big]\,.
$$
This shows
$$\tag{3}
\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_0^Tr(u)\,du\Big)\frac{R(T)}{R(S)}\Big]=\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_0^Sr(u)\,du\Big)\Big]=P(0,S)\,.
$$
Using the fact that $P(S,T)$ is ${\cal F}_S$-measurable (i.e. known at time $S$) the tower property of conditional expectations implies
\begin{align}
&\textstyle\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_0^Tr(u)\,du\Big)\frac{1}{P(S,T)}\Big]\\[3mm]
&=\textstyle\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_0^Tr(u)\,du\Big)\frac{1}{P(S,T)} \Big|{\cal F}_S\Big]\Big]\\[3mm]
&\textstyle=\mathbb E\Big[ \frac{\exp(-\int_0^Sr(u)\,du)}{P(S,T)}\underbrace{\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_S^Tr(u)\,du\Big)\Big|{\cal F}_S\Big]}_{P(S,T)}\Big]\\[3mm]
&\textstyle=\mathbb E\Big[\exp\Big(-\int_0^Sr(u)\,du\Big)\Big]=P(0,S)\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
\boxed{\text{The fact that (3) and (4) are equal shows that the swap PVs must agree exactly.}}
$$
If instead you have options on $L(S,T,S)$ and $I(S,T)$ you can see from (1) that $I(S,T)$ has a larger volatility since it takes time until $T$ until this overnight rate is known. In contrast, the libor $L(S,T,S)$ is known at time $S<T$ and therefore has a lower volatility.